# Using sshfs freezes all terminals

Tags: terminal, freeze, sshfs

I am trying to mount directories from my work machine on my laptop via sshfs. The command I'm running is

```
sshfs -d -o allow_other -o reconnect -o ServerAliveInterval=15 server:~/Documents ~/Documents/home
```

The corresponding entry in `~/.ssh/config` is

```
Host server
    User myname
    Port 22
    ProxyCommand ssh -q -W machineName.serverAdress.com:%p WorkNetworkName
```

Now everytime I run the command I just get

```
FUSE library version: 2.9.4
nullpath_ok: 0
nopath: 0
utime_omit_ok: 0
```

and then nothing. I can't even kill the process or unmount since in all other terminals I can enter a command but it won't run. The only thing I can do then is put the laptop to sleep and wake it up again. When I then run `ls` in `~/Documents` on my laptop I get:

```
d????????? ? ?      ?         ?            ? home
```

And `fish` throws the following error message on every letter I type:

```
fish: Error while searching for command “/home/username/Documents/home/bin/python_lib/ls”
access: Transport endpoint is not connected
```

where `~/bin/python_lib` is a directory I keep my python scripts on my work machine, so this is part of my `PYTHONPATH` on my work machine.

Can anyone see what I did wrong?

Cheers

Comment: I think this `server:~/Documents` can't work. Better try `server:Documents`

Comment: @rudimeier It works: the local shell doesn't expand the tilde because it isn't after an equal sign, and the remote shell expands the tilde.

Comment: SSHFS has no problem with `home` as a directory name. I suspect that either something in your desktop environment is watching for mount points, or you have a search path that includes this volume. What desktop environment are you running? What is the output of `export | grep Documents` ?

Comment: @Gilles are you sure there is a remote *shell* involved at all? For me `~ ` is not expanded on the remote `server:~: No such file or directory`

Comment: It works with `~` for me.

Comment: @rudimeier Uh, no, sorry, brain fart. Sshfs does not invoke a shell (ssh always uses a shell, except with sftp, and sshfs uses sftp) and the tile is not expanded at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay the problem was that the actual name of `mountPoint` was `home` and somehow that was too much for sshfs. If anyone knows why it's not a good idea to call the mount point `home` I'd be happy to learn something here.

Cheers

Comment: [SSHFS FAQ](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs/blob/master/FAQ)
Is a question 23 your case?

Comment: Not really question 23 is about using `~` in the remote path but that was not my problem. My problem was only fixed once I changed the local name of the mount point from `home` to `homeDir`.

Comment: Please update your question to show a way that actually reproduces the problem.